# How to check if a session is still valid: Laravel and Vue

Tags: laravel, session, vue.js, axios

I'm using Laravel with Vue and Axios (for ajax calls).
I need to check if the session is still valid before ajax calls to save content or to access private pages.

I tried `interceptors.push` to check the response status like they say here:
[Check Laravel login session](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/check-laravel-login-session?page=1) but I always got `undefined`. I tried:

```
Vue.http.interceptors.push
this.http.interceptors.push
this.$http.interceptors.push
this.http.interceptors.push
```

Then I read I should use axios instead but I don't understand how.
Do you have a better solution to solve this problem?

Comment: Your routes should be guarded by some type of authenticatable middleware, and return a response when sessions are invalid, such as `419` (which is Laravel's default). Use a `response interceptor` to interrogate the response codes and if 419, destroy the client side session and redirect them to the login page.

Comment: thanks but how to use response interceptor?

Comment: Another solution is to just keep the session alive by sending out an ajax call every minute or so. Then it wont expire until an explicit logout action.

Comment: To answer your question, this is how: https://github.com/niiknow/laratt-api/blob/master/resources/js/services/vue-axios.js#L23  See also line 7, which tell Vue to use axios for http/$http

Comment: I did this before my ajax call

axios.interceptors.response.use(
    response => {
        console.log(response);
    }
)
But the status is always 200 even after I deleted the session through the Chrome Dev tool